# Dynamic element height not affecting all instances individually

Tags: jquery

I've written some jQuery that dynamically sets a 4:3 aspect ratio height on `img` elements whose parents have the `.four-three-img` class. It's working as expected, except in cases where a single page contains `.four-three-img` elements with different widths.

For example, if there are two `section`s containing `.four-three-img img` elements, it will determine the height of the first `img` within the first `section` and apply it to the remaining `img`s in the first and second `section` elements, which may be smaller or larger. I've tried placing the script within a for loop, but it made no difference.

Here's the script:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  var fourThreeHeight = $('.four-three-img').width() * 0.75;

  $('.four-three-img img').each(function() {
    $(this).height(fourThreeHeight);
  });
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/apWjmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the `fourThreeHeight`-variable inside the `each`-function, and change `$('.four-three-img')` to `$(this)`:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  $('.four-three-img img').each(function() {
    var fourThreeHeight = $(this).width() * 0.75;
    $(this).height(fourThreeHeight);
  });
});
```

Having it outside the `each`-function will cause, only the width of the first element to be stored, and not each elements.

[Live Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPbGXX)

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I see it working as I'd like in Codepen, but for some reason, it's not making a difference in my project.

Comment: Never mind–I hadn't updated the element reference to `$(this)` on `.width()`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)